# why does ESRI Maps For Office login window disappear and did not login?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-portal, esri-maps-office

I recently tried out the ESRI maps for office. After in installed it, i tried to login in excel. it was a success. I then proceed to try it out in PowerPoint.

However, when the sign in window appear and i entered the username and password and click sign in, the window just disappear and not signed in.

i could still see the sign in button in the ribbon instead of 'sign out' which would show if i have successfully login. i tried searching for similar issues but haven't found any.

I tried reinstalling but doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Does anyone know what is the cause of it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After extensive reading, i found out that the issue comes from the self signed certificate i used. This will cause problems. The self signed cert needs to be added to the **Trusted Root Certification Authority**. Once it's in there, there will be no untrusted warning if you open up portal using IE. This means that it has been trusted. Thus, it will solve the issue with esri maps for office PowerPoint.